# O que é deploy?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, intellij

Cada módulo do projeto possui um `.war` e um `.war exploded`, quais são as funções desse artifacts nesse processo de "deploy"? E qual a função do Jenkins nesse contexto? Entendo que deploy é um processo de "montar esse war" pois toda vez que algo está errado recebo um **Build failed in Jenkins**.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Em termos gerais, ***deploy*** significa ***colocar em posição***.

Na prática, geralmente falamos de disponibilizar um sistema para uso, seja num ambiente de desenvolvimento, para testes ou em produção.

## Sobrecarga do termo

Um termo *deploy* pode significar muitas coisas, dependendo do ambiente e da tecnologia. Um desenvolvedor pode fazer o *deploy* da aplicação web no seu Tomcat local. Pode também fazer o *deploy* no Weblogic de produção, usado pelos usuários reais.

## Nível de automação

O *deploy* pode ser *"manual"*, *parcialmente automatizado* ou *completamente automatizado*.

Um processo *manual* pode consistir em exportar um WAR no Eclipse, acessar a página de adminitração do Tomcat e fazer o upload do WAR.

Um processo automatizado pode consistir em comitar o código no repositório, sendo que esta ação dispara automaticamente o processo de construção (*build*) do "executável" da aplicação e possivelmente sua disponibilização em um servidor.

## Personalização

Embora o ciclo de vida de uma aplicação possa estar 100% automatizado, não significa que um *commit* qualquer vai acabar em produção. O importante é que todos os passos mais trabalhosos estejam automatizados, disponíveis a um comando do desenvolvedor ou responsável.

Desenvolvedores e administradores devem configurar todo esse ambiente da forma que seja mais adequada ao projeto, minimizando retrabalho, tarefas repetitivas e erro humano em todo o ciclo de vida de uma aplicação, que vai desde a especificação até a aceitação do usuário final.

Por exemplo, nem sempre faz sentido um código comitado gerar uma versão do sistema em produção. Então vários critérios podem ser adotados para que novas funcionalidades implementadas sejam devidamente entregues ao usuário final. A principal estratégia aqui é o uso correto de ramificações (*branches*) de desenvolvimento.

## Integração Contínua (CI - *Continuous Integration*)

Toda essa automatização não visa apenas evitar trabalho repetitivo. Ela na verdade permite aos desenvolvedores alcançaram um nível muito maior de produtividade e qualidade.

Um problema recorrente no desenvolvimento de software é que os erros ocultos nos programas que desenvolvemos são cada vez mais caros e difíceis de corrigir na medido em que o tempo passa.

Qualquer pessoa que trabalha com programação já deve ter passado pela situação de achar que um programa estava quase pronto e "só faltava testar", para então descobrir que, na verdade, muito coisa ainda estava errada ou mesmo faltando no código.

Outra situação recorrente é a "preguiça" de testar o software, ou pelo menos a prática de postergar os testes. Sem testes e *deploy* automatizados, o desenvolvedor tende a escrever uma grande quantidade de código antes de realmente colocar o programa para executar, afinal se o processo é trabalhoso e toma muito tempo, ele vai evitar de fazer isso ao máximo. Só que no final gasta-se muito tempo para corrigir todos os "detalhes" que não estava corretos.

Para mitigar todos esses problemas, surgiu o conceito de Integração Contínua. A ideia é justamente automatizar o processo para que com bastante frequência, uma ou mais vezes ao dia, seja possível integrar todas as alterações de todos os desenvolvedores envolvidos no projeto e realizar um teste geral.

## Automação do ciclo de vida de uma aplicação

Fazer Integração Contínua nem sempre é uma tarefa simples e existem muitas formas de fazer isso.

### Construção (*Build*)

O *build* é o processo que transforma seu código-fonte em um "executável", como um Jar ou War em Java. É claro que você pode usar um script próprio executando o `javac`, mas existem ferramentas mais avançadas como Ant ou Maven.

Um dos métodos mais comuns de fazer isso em Java é a utilização de alguma ferramenta como o [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). O Maven gerencia a construção (**build**) dos projetos através do uso de convenções e padrões. Por exemplo, os projetos que usam Maven geralmente seguem a seguinte estrutura de diretórios:

[image: Estruturas de diretório do maven]

Basicamente, você coloca os códigos-fonte da aplicação em `src/main/java` e os testes automatizados em `src/test/java`.

O Maven também define uma série de fases da construção do projeto. Veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: Fases de construção do projeto]

Vamos analisar as fases principais:

- Compile: faz a compilação do código dos diretórios `src/*/java`.
- Test: executa os testes encontrados no diretório `src/test/java`
- Package: empacota as classes e outros arquivos em um JAR ou WAR, por exemplo.

Há também uma fase de *deploy* que pode ser configurada para disponibilizar o "executável" gerado em um servidor. No entanto, cada tipo de servidor precisa de um plugin diferente do Maven.

Enfim, seguindo os padrões definidos, que podem também ser personalizados, o Maven permite automatizar todo o processo de *build* ou construção do projeto. Há também uma fase

Se quiser saber mais sobre o Maven, sugiro a leitura do artigo:

> [***Instalando, configurando e usando o Maven para gerenciar suas dependências e seus projetos Java***](http://luizricardo.org/2014/06/instalando-configurando-e-usando-o-maven-para-gerenciar-suas-dependencias-e-seus-projetos-java/)

### Gerenciando em alto nível

Construir o projeto é o passo mais importante, mas a Integração Contínua precisa levar em conta todo o ambiente da empresa. Afinal, nem sempre o desenvolvedor pode ou deve ter acesso direto para fazer o *deploy* de sua máquina local.

Nesses casos, o ambiente de desenvolvimento de uma empresa pode dividir o trabalho entre diversos servidores contendo serviços especializados. Aqui entram aplicações omo o Jenkins para "colocar ordem na bagunça".

Considere a ilustração abaixo:

[image: Integração Contínua com Jenkins]

Em resumo, os passos ilustrados são:

1. ***Check in***: é quando o desenvolvedor faz o *commit* ou *merge* do código na *branch* configurada para *releases* do projeto no sistema de versionamento (VCS - *Version Control System*). A *branch* principal geralmente é chamada de `HEAD` no CVS, `Trunk` no SVN e `master` no Git, mas pode ser qualquer outra arbitrariamente definida.
2. A alteração no seu VCS dispara então um processo no seu Servidor de Integração Contínua (*CI Server*), que pode ser o próprio Jenkins. O servidor irá disparar o *build* do projeto nos servidores de *build* (*build servers*).
3. Se o projeto usa Maven, por exemplo, o *build server* irá então compilar, testar e empacotar o projeto usando essa ferramenta. Primeiro ele recupera o código-fonte (*check out*) do VCS e depois, por exemplo, executa o comando `mvn package`.
4. Após o término do *build* o *CI Server* (nosso Jenkins) recupera o relatório da compilação e dos testes e verifica se tudo ocorreu bem.
5. O *CI Server* atualiza então o status do projeto.
6. O *CI Server*, de acordo com a configuração, notifica os interessados no resultado do processo.

Dentro do processo acima, opcionalmente, poderia haver um passo para fazer o *deploy* da aplicação em um servidor. Uma forma seria através do próprio *build* do Maven. Outra seria configurar o Jenkins para executar o *deploy* após o *build* (passo #4).

No entanto, considero mais interessante a abordagem de *promover* determinados *builds* concluídos com sucesso de forma manual. O processo ainda seria todo automatizado, mas ao final o responsável pelo projeto pode selecionar um determinado *build* que acabou de sair de desenvolvimento e, com um clique, *promovê-lo* para o ambiente de testes ou mesmo para produção.

Comment: "Terminei, agora só falta testar" é sensacional :P

Answer (score 14):

*Deploy* quer dizer implantar. Por exemplo, depois que você gerou o seu programa e quer colocar ele no ar em seu servidor de aplicação, o que você está fazendo é implantando ele no servidor. Implantar significa colocar no ar, e o termo para isso em inglês é *deploy*. Também é importante não confundir *implantar* com *implementar*, são coisas bem diferentes e já vi muita gente fazendo confusão entre estes dois termos.

O Jenkins é apenas o programa que automatiza o processo de construção. Ele invoca o compilador, executa os testes, roda o javadoc e executa qualquer que seja o processo para fazer a implantação e ainda armazena o histórico de cada processo de construção do seu programa bem como os artefatos gerados. Esse erro apenas diz que o processo de construção (normalmente compilação) falhou e que quem estava rodando este processo era o Jenkins.

O WAR é a "coisa" que é de fato implantada em um servidor web. Nada mais é do que um arquivo JAR com algumas configurações especiais. No entanto, dentro deste WAR podem existir outros arquivos JAR aninhados. Para que tudo possa ser executado no servidor, ele precisa ser explodido - ou seja, todo o conteúdo dos JARs aninhados deve ser extraído para dentro do WAR, desfazendo-se o aninhamento e resultando em uma hierarquia mais plana que consista apenas do WAR contendo as classes da sua aplicação (incluindo os que estavam em JARs), eliminando então os JARs aninhados.

Por fim, para implantar a sua aplicação, o Jenkins vai fazer no mínimo o seguinte: Compilar ela, gerar um WAR a partir dele (talvez explodido, dependendo de como for configurado) e então implantar ele no seu servidor de aplicação (que no seu caso é o Tomcat).

Comment: Aqui está uma resposta bem resumida e concisa, excelente +1